# excel vba run existing access query runtime error

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010, vba

Need help about the error. I'm trying to use excel VBA to run an existing ACCESS  query with parameters. I am getting Run-time error '-2147217911 (80040e90): Automation error. After setting up checking point and it seems like the problem comes the code "rs.Open cmd". Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot.

The code is as below:

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

With con
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open "U:\databases\myaccessdatabase.mdb"
End With

With cmd
    .activeconnection = con
    .CommandText = "myquery"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("startdate", adDBDate, adParamInput, , "11/01/2015")

    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("startdate", adDBDate, adParamInput, , "11/30/2015")

End With


'run query and paste the result into the excel
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open cmd
Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

 '  The following is the code for write the log information into the VBA immediate window
    Do Until rs.EOF
       Debug.Print rs.Fields("ID").Value
      rs.MoveNext
    Loop

 ' Close and release the sources from the system

rs.Close
con.Close

Set cmd = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set prm = Nothing
Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Update: I tested my code with a query on a local table, it works perfect. However, the problem came when the query is on a linked ODBC table.